# Separate result from Microsoft SQL Server query on an xml with CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to learn writing stored procedures, passing in a xml file as an argument, and return a modified select result set.

Basically I have a XML file. I want to make a select query where it would separate `SubElementB` with commas (CSV in short) using the select statement I have below. Basically the result set I want in the `ElementAB` column would be (-1, -2, -3, -4) on top of the other columns from the select statement. The order doesn't matter for now.

I'm struggling how to make it work. So far I've managed to read from an XML file so that's a bonus. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the SQL Fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84e27/4)

XML File:

```
<ElementA>
    <ElementAA>false</ElementAA>
    <ElementAB>
        <SubElementB>-1</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>2</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>3</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>-4</SubElementB>
    </ElementAB>
    <ElementAC>Some text for element AC</ElementAC>
</ElementA>
```

SQL Statement:

```
select 
    m.c.value('(ElementAA/.)[1]', 'bit') as ElementAA,
    m.c.value('(ElementAB/.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ElementAB,
    m.c.value('(ElementAC/.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ElementAC
from 
    sqm as s
cross apply 
    s.data.nodes('Sqm/ElementA') as m(c)
```

Result from the query is:

```
ElementAA | ElementAB | ElementAC  
false     | -123-4    | Some text for element AC
```

What I want is:

```
ElementAA | ElementAB   | ElementAC  
false     | -1,2,3,-4   | Some text for element AC
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result ?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post. results that i want are at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: string parsing `stuff(replace(m.c.value('(ElementAB/.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),'-',',-'),1,1,'')`

Comment: [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84e27/10)

Comment: From my understanding, the query you suggested replaces the minus sign with another minus sign with a comma. It doesn't work with positive values sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the best approach to get this done, but it works

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<ElementA>
    <ElementAA>false</ElementAA>
    <ElementAB>
        <SubElementB>-1</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>2</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>3</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>-4</SubElementB>
    </ElementAB>
    <ElementAC>Some text for element AC</ElementAC>
</ElementA>';

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT m.c.value('(ElementAA/.)[1]', 'bit')           AS ElementAA,
                m1.c.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')          AS ElementAB,
                m.c.value('(ElementAC/.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ElementAC
         FROM   (SELECT @xml data) AS s
                CROSS apply s.data.nodes('/ElementA') AS m(c)
                CROSS apply s.data.nodes('/ElementA/ElementAB/SubElementB') AS m1(c))
SELECT DISTINCT a.ElementAA,
                ElementAB = Stuff(cs.ElementAB, 1, 1, ''),
                a.ElementAC
FROM   cte a
       CROSS apply (SELECT ',' + ElementAB
                    FROM   cte b
                    WHERE  a.ElementAA = b.ElementAA
                    FOR xml path('')) cs (ElementAB)
```

**Result :**

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ ElementAA ║ ElementAB ║        ElementAC         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║         0 ║ -1,2,3,-4 ║ Some text for element AC ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: It works! I'll be playing around with it and see if i can come up with a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<ElementA>
    <ElementAA>false</ElementAA>
    <ElementAB>
        <SubElementB>-1</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>2</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>3</SubElementB>
        <SubElementB>-4</SubElementB>
    </ElementAB>
    <ElementAC>Some text for element AC</ElementAC>
</ElementA>';

SELECT @xml.value(N'(/ElementA/ElementAA/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ElementAA
      ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + se.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
        FROM @xml.nodes(N'/ElementA/ElementAB/SubElementB') AS A(se)
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ListOfSubElementB
      ,@xml.value(N'(/ElementA/ElementAC/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ElementAC
```

The result

```
ElementAA   ListOfSubElementB   ElementAC
false       -1,2,3,-4           Some text for element AC
```

But - to be honest - this cries for a more generic approach...